# Using Ramcloud python bindings API is there a way to query all the data (key, value) in a table?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, ramcloud

I have something like following,

```
c = ramcloud.RAMCloud()
c.connect(....)
c.create_table('employee') 
c.create(<tableid>, 'id1', 'name1') 
c.create(<tableid>, 'id2', 'name2')
c.create(<tableid>, 'id3', 'name3')
```

is there a way to query all the data by something like `c.read(<tableid>)` instead of providing `c.read(<tableid>, key)`?

Answer (score 0):

The Python binding only provide the function read() with two parameter. So there is not other way as of now to read the table details as you have mentioned.